# How can I retrieve the n size elements of this list?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the below code which retrieves the value in the `getNames.get(x)`, `getNames()` is of type `List<String>`. The requirement is to create an account, based on the size of the `getNames()`. This can vary from 1 to x, so rather than write the below, how can I use streams to accommodate this? Failing that, perhaps a loop will suffice. Final result should be based on the size of `getNames()`, `createAccount()` is called the same number of times.

```
    public List<Account> buildAccounts(MetaData metaData){
return List.of(
    createAccount(metaData.getNames().get(0)), 
    createAccount(metaData.getNames().get(1)), 
    createAccount(metaData.getNames().get(2)));
}

public Account createAccount(String name){
....
}
```

The length can be calculated using `metaData.getNames().stream.collect(Collectors.counting());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a good candidate for `map`.

```
public public List<Account> buildAccounts(MetaData metaData){
    return metaData.getNames().stream()
                              .map(n -> createAccount(n))
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

As an aside

> The length can be calculated using
> `metaData.getNames().stream.collect(Collectors.counting());`

That would be weird when you can simply do `metaData.getNames().size()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Stream#map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-).

> Returns a stream consisting of the results of applying the given function to the elements of this stream.

```
return metaData.getNames().stream()
    .map(name -> createAccount(name)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In Java 16+, the `collect` call can be shortened to [`.toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toList()).

Answer (score 1):

For the size of the list you can use the `size()` method `metaData.getNames().size();`

For creating account

```
public List<Account> buildAccounts(MetaData metaData) {
    return metaData.getNames()
            .stream()
            .map(this::createAccount)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Another approach with for-each loop (enhanced for loop)

```
public List<Account> buildAccounts(MetaData metaData) {
    List<String> names = metaData.getNames();
    List<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<>(names.size());

    for (String name : names) {
        var account = createAccount(name);
        accounts.add(account);
    }

    return accounts;
}
```